# Cannot set breakpoint in .vue file with async method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having issues debugging my Vue app in that stepping can skip lines or breakpoints cannot be set on a valid line.

I guess it's a sourcemap issue but not sure where to start digging. Likely one of Vue-loader, Webpack or Babel.

Tested with:

> vue: 2.6.10
>
> vue-cli 4.1.2

The issue can be reproduced as follows:

create new Vue project:

> vue create test

Just use the defaults

> cd test
>
> npm run serve

Replace HelloWorld.vue with:

```js
<template>
  <button @click="save()">
    Save
  </button>

</template>

<script>
export default {

  methods: {

    async save() {
      debugger;
      let valid = false;
      if (valid) {
        return;
      } else {
        console.log("Hi")
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Open devtools in Chrome, hit the save button and try put breakpoint on the line:

```
if (valid) {
```

In my test the breakpoint isn't set.

If I remove *async* from the save method, the breakpoint can be set.

tested with Chrome 79 and Firefox 73.

I've also played around with various devtool settings in vue.config.js without success eg:

```
devtool = 'cheap-module-eval-sourcemap' 
devtool = 'cheap-eval-source-map' 
devtool = 'source-map'
```

Any ideas?

Kind regards

Bob

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue; can't debug in an async method. Would love to hear of any fixes for this!

Answer (score 3):

No idea why it does not work in this specific case, but as a means of last resort, you can add a line `debugger;` before `if...` - is will make any DevTools (at least any current one, incl. IE11) stop there. You code would then look something like this:

```
      // ...
      debugger;
      if (valid) {
        // ...
```

Comment: Yep, that's the approach I'm using. But the app is growing and I need a smooth debug experience, especially "Step". Currently stepping isn't very usable in my app. The past year (2019) there were some fixes in Vue and Webpack to make stepping more accurate. But seems some gremlins could be present still ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because of the Babel polyfills Vue CLI is configured to use by default which generated source maps don't seem to work well with.

Specifically this polyfill for async methods will cause issues with debugging:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator

You can avoid these polyfills by adding this in your .browserslistrc

```
[development]
last 1 chrome version
last 1 firefox version
```

The [@vue/babel-preset-app](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/babel-preset-app) Babel preset automatically determines which polyfills to use based on which browsers you are targeting in .browserslistrc. So to disable the problematic polyfill we target only browsers that natively support async/await in development (eg: the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: This didn't work for me, checked in Current Chrome, FF, and Edge, and made sure async generators weren't being created by babel. Breakpoints still only register correctly until the first time the code drops into an async method, after which point breakpoints seem to map to random irrelevant code.

Comment: @npjohns the random irrelevant code is likely a polyfill. Try searching some of the function names to find out which polyfill it is and then find a way to stop that polyfill from being used in development.